# Creating several database tables for user data?

Tags: database, database-design

I need to have a lot of user data in the database. Now, I've been thinking about having two tables, *users* that would have only the **id**, **username** and **password** and another table *userData* that would have everything else like **name**, **lastname** etc.

Is this a prefered method?

Comment: "Is this a prefered method?"  Preferred for what?  Complexity?  Slowness?  Privacy?

Comment: I wouldn't store password with id and username, as passwords could (and should) change - you may want to store them in a separate table so you can store a history of passwords, encrypt that table etc. Depends on your complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest design would put all the fields in one table.  From that point, though, there are a bunch of reasons you might want to consider splitting that information up into multiple tables.  From your description, I cant' tell whether there are any valid reasons to do so.

If you start with one table, you might find it advantageous to split the data for reasons such as:

- Normalization.
- Reducing contention (different parts of the app update different information)
- Truly huge column lists (look into the limit for your DB)
- Other?? (how you're going to maintain your app, maybe?)

In short, I'd try to start simple and have a reason to pick the more complex design if you go that route.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with that design IMHO.  You can have a `users` table and link it to a `users_custom` table that has additional information.  Just be consistant with your design.  Just remember that in order to get any additional user information you will always have to `JOIN` to that data.

To me this is a matter of preference, if you feel that this table will grow over time, consider your design, if not just keep it all in one table and properly index columns that you deem necessary.

You can go further by having a `UserLog` table to build a historical view of values as they change.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is :) In theory there are this so called "normal forms" (3NF BCnF, etc...). Using them, means seperating table into smaller ones :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be better for you to keep it all in one table.  Assuming you will be enforcing unique usernames, all the fields (password, first_name, and last_name) have a functional dependency on username.  Therefore, you can put them all in the same table and still have a normalized database.

Although you can certainly separate first_name and last_name into their own table, queries will get a lot easier (fewer JOINs) if you keep all those fields in one table.